# How to run a Qt-based program on windows

Tags: qt, mingw

Recently, I've written a program using the Qt Creator. It runs well when I execute it using the IDE, but when I want to run the .exe file alone, warnings appear that files like mingw10.dll, QtCore4.dll, etc. are missing from the computer. Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to install mingw first and then download Qt Creator with Qt SDK. You can see making qt creator use mingw

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a Qt application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621262/how-to-run-a-qt-application)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/621337/1758762

If you have built a 'release' version of your program, copy it and the following DLL's from qt\bin to a directory:

QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll and mingwm10.dll (if you are compiling with gcc and minGW).

Comment: Thanks. But now still when I want to run the program, it keeps telling me that: The procedure entry point ??0QPointF@@QAE@NN@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll. What should I do?

Comment: Please be aware copied the right library, there are many ones (/bin/QtCore4.dll, /lib/QtCore4.dll, QtCreator/bin/QtCore4.dll).The right one you cat check with dumpbin QtCore4.dll /exports in the console. It should be a one from QtCreator/bin I think but check first please.

Comment: @duDE the ones from _QtCreator/bin_ are usually the ones built with VS that Creator uses, so the correct ones are _/bin/QtCore4.dll_ (and _/lib/QtCore4.dll_ should be identical with _/bin/QtCore4.dll_ )

Answer (score 1):

You copy those dlls from: MinGW_install\bin and qt_install_path\bin in the same folder with your application.

A cool tool you can use to see what is needed is [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

And also you can read more in [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) - they present there the static build too you create a big exe that doesn't need Qt dlls - but note that you have to build Qt yourself and LGPL has some restriction about that (so i guess you can ignore the static build part and read about the plugins deployment there)

Comment: Would you please explain more about the static build part? Thanks

Comment: You can build Qt statically (you need to rebuild the Qt framework from source), basic steps are download and unzip the source code, run _configure.exe -static_ (plus - the other options you might need) and run _nmake_ (if you use Visual Studio) or _mingw32-make_ (for MinGW) to actually build the Qt framework, anyway first read about it in the documentation link and also if you use open source Qt read about LGPL restrictions regarding static linkage.