# Error running Qt executable - missing DLL

Tags: qt, build, executable

I've compiled my project to run and when I launch the executable, I get a windows error:

"The program cannot start because Qt5Cored.dll is missing from your computer. Try re-installing the program to fix this problem."

I'm assuming it wants me to re-install QtCreator, but my question is, can I build the project as a stand-alone executable? One that doesn't require an installation of Qt to run it? This is a test program that needs to run on multiple computers... Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a Qt-based program on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560041/how-to-run-a-qt-based-program-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can build Qt libraries statically. But in this case you should buy Qt licence or distribute your sources via LGPL.
2. You need to read about [deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html)

Comment: Well, this program is proprietary, it can't be used with anything but my hardware... plus it falls under ITAR regulations, so I'm not allowed anything but in-office use and definitely not allowed to share anything... so if I must buy a license, I must buy a license. Thanks!

Comment: @JediEngineer it is not necessary to buy licence for proprietary applications. It is enough to take necessary .dll's with your .exe. Just read link, that I provided.

Comment: I did read it, thank you. Had to run to a meeting before I got the chance to thank you. Thanks!! :-)  I'll post back if I run into any problems in the next day or two.